# "The type or namespace could not be found" error while building a project

Tags: c#, .net

I am getting this error while trying to build a solution:

> Error  CS0246
>   The type or namespace name 'ClassName' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The error and the red lines disappear when I open the error list and click on it. I can see the missing dll file is recognized by that class and it is also listed in the references.

I searched many questions here but none of them worked for me. Here is a list of things I tried so far that might help to understand the problem.

- I've got the project from TFS and have been never able to build so far. I think the project is not correctly checked in.
- I choose 'build only' in the Error list section, after that the errors did not disappear.
- All project versions are .Net 4.6, none of them is Client Profile like other in questions here.
- I tried to clean, to rebuild, deleting references and adding them again, but none of them worked.

Comment: If the project isn't correctly checked in, how can we help with that?  We can't see any part of your project, nor do we know anything about your project other than it doesn't build.

Comment: You're missing an assembly reference.  I don't think we can tell you any more than that based on the limited information about the missing class and how you're trying to use it.

Comment: I am not sure it isn't correctly checked in, i am guessing there might be problem in csproj files. The problem is i got error while building but when i click error and go to classes errors are disappearing in a second. It doesnot look like specific dll file because i got same error for 4 ddls and i can also navigate to them with f12 key. I thought there might be some solution to fix csproj or change build options to prevent that kind of error.

Comment: @onurdemir if you build your project/solution with msbuild on the commandline msbuild will tell you if references can't be resolved or are ignored as info in the middle of the logs

Comment: Thanks, I did not build the solution with msbuild but i did similar thing to see more details in output and it helped my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have changed build output to Diagnostic then inspected errors.

[image]

I have found this line and changed all projects target version from 4.6 to 4.6.2 and it worked.

> Dll could not be resolved because it was built against the
>   ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2" framework. This is a higher version
>   than the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6".